# How can I get two lines in a table cell when using Word.ConvertToTable

Tags: c#, ms-word, multiline

I can't find a way to get multiple lines into a single table cell when converting a custom string to a Word table.
Basicly I want to have a soft return in the cell to show two items in the same cell.

The strings are generated external, no fixed cell where multiple lines should be used.

Test:

```
string testTable = "date@test@result@";
testTable = testTable + "1/07/2016@test1@123@";
testTable = testTable + "2/07/2016@test2|test2bis@456@";
testTable = testTable + "3/07/2016@test3@789";

 object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
 object oSeperator = "@";
 object oNumColumns = 3;
 object oNumRows = 3;
 object oApplyBorders = true;
 object oApplyTrue = true;
 object oApplyFalse = false;
 object oFormat = Word.WdTableFormat.wdTableFormatGrid3;
 object oAutoFit = false;
 Word.Table MyTable = selection.ConvertToTable(ref oSeperator, ref oNumRows, ref oNumColumns, missing, ref oFormat, ref oApplyBorders, missing, missing, missing, ref oApplyFalse, missing, missing,
                        missing, ref oAutoFit, missing, missing);
```

[image: Example manually altered table]

ConvertToTable should create a table where test2 and test2bis are in the same cell in different lines. Something you can easily do manually after the table is created by using a shift-enter or enter in the cell.

I've tried replacing the '|' with '\p', '\l' or '\n' but all options shift test2bis to the first column on the next tablerow. Using '^p' or '\u2028' just adds this as text.

Hoping I missed something and this can be done automatically by having the right character in the string. The only other option i see is to loop over all cells again after the table is created and try to insert the soft return then, but this would make it pretty complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the new line in the cells with a

```
\v
```

eg

```
testTable = testTable + "2/07/2016@test2\vtest2bis@456@";
```